# Why scanf() always return nothing?

Tags: c, char, scanf

Hi i need help about this:

```
 int t;
 t = 1;
 char abc[256];
 int main() {
 scanf("%s", abc);
 if(abc == "google") {
  printf("%s \n", abc);
  system("firefox");
 } else
  printf("error");
}
```

it always return error please someone help!
i already tried `scanf("%c", &abc);` and i rewrote this about 5 times with the same result.
I'm new at this so this can be a very stupid thing.

Comment: Use `strcmp` to compare strings brother .

Comment: Its not `scanf` problem . It is because you compare strings incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `if(abc == "google") {`

   This doesn't do what you think it does. This checks whether the *pointers* to those two strings are numerically equal. They never will be, because `abc` is allocated in the stack, and `"google"` is a string literal and therefore has static storage duration.

   You should use `strcmp` like ameyCU points out.
2. In general, don't use `scanf` like this, the code you wrote is vulnerable to buffer overflow attacks if someone passes a large string.

   You might want to look at this nice post about how to use `scanf` safely. [How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the problem! and thanks for this fast answer!!

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare the *contents* of two character arrays with `==`. `==` will just compare the memory addresses of the arrays (after array-to-pointer decay).

Use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) instead:

```
if (strcmp(abc, "google") == 0) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The constant string "google" reside in the .rodata section of your program and if you compile with all warning -Wall you get this warning

```
google.c:10:12: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
if(abc == "google") {
```

and this code is equivalent with

```
const char* const google_str = "google";
if(abc == google_str)
```

Here both the string "google" and the address to that string is constant. So you see you are doing a pointer comparison and not a string comparison.

```
printf("%p == %p\n", abc, google_str);
```

This code will show you that abc reside on the stack and that google_str reside in the .rodata section. String comparison should be done with

```
if(0 == strcmp(abc, "google")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
if(abc == "google")
</code>
```

would work in object oriented languages like java and dot net
in c cpp you have to use inbuild library functions of String like strcpy,strcmp

```
<code> int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2) <code>
```

compares the string pointed to, by str1 to the string pointed to by str2.

So you will modify your code as

```
  #include <stdio.h>
     int t;
     t = 1;
     char abc[256],a[256];
    int main()
    {
        strcpy(a,"google");
        scanf("%s", abc);

        if( strcmp("abc","google")==0 ) {
            printf("%s \n", abc);
            printf("firefox");
     } else
      printf("error");

        return 0;
    }
```